# Motivo de IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, jar

Recentemente percebi algumas mensagens de erro no meu código, a mensagem que aparece é essa:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

O estranho é que somente acontece com o `jar` pronto e em outras máquinas, na máquina onde eu gerei o `jar` funciona normalmente.

Qual o motivo dessa exceção e como posso evitar que aconteça?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um erro do tipo `IncompatibleClassChangeError` normalmente é efeito de um processo de compilação inadequado.

Por exemplo:

1. Crie as seguintes classes:

   ```
   public class Teste {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Teste2.hello();
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   public class Teste2 {
       public static void hello() {
           System.out.println("Oi");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Compile as classes assim:

   ```
   javac Teste.java Teste2.java
   ```
3. Altere a classe `Teste2`, removendo o modificador `static`:

   ```
   public class Teste2 {
       public void hello() {
           System.out.println("Oi");
       }
   }
   ```
4. Recompile somente a classe `Teste2`:

   ```
   javac Teste2.java
   ```
5. Execute o programa:

   ```
   java Teste
   ```

Eis a saída:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method Teste2.hello()V
>         at Teste.main(Teste.java:3)
> ```

Há várias outras formas de se gerar um `IncompatibleClassChangeError`, mas todas elas são fruto de misturar classes que foram alteradas e recompiladas de formas incompatíveis entre si. A melhor sugestão para se corrigir isso é apagar quaisquer arquivos `.class` do seu projeto e recompilar tudo de novo a partir do zero.